# Отображение карты на сайте(yandex-map)

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Мне нужно добавить карту с разным функционалом на сайт.Я взял ключ апи в яндексе(сервис «JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер»).Взял хтмл код из документации

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Быстрый старт. Размещение интерактивной карты на странице</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/3.0/?apikey=(апи ключ мой)&lang=ru_RU"></script>
    <script>
      ymaps3.ready.then(init);
      function init() {
      const map = new ymaps3.YMap(document.getElementById('YMapsID'), {
  location: {
    center: [37.64, 55.76],
    zoom: 10
  }
});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Я вставил данный код на сайт,после чего ничего не отображалось,в поддержке ответили чтобы для отображения карты нужно добавить еще слои,так как я не самый шарящий человек в коде и в документации не нашел куда именно вставлять и как правильно.Так вот может кто знает как решить мою проблему,и как добиться результатат отображения карты на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Слой с подложкой следует добавлять в тело функции **init()**, которая у вас в блоке `<script>`. Минимальный вид скрипта для отображения карты будет выглядеть так:

```
ymaps3.ready.then(init);
function init() {
    const map = new ymaps3.YMap(document.getElementById('YMapsID'), {
        location: {
            center: [37.64, 55.76],
            zoom: 10
        }
    });
    
     const layer = new ymaps3.YMapDefaultSchemeLayer();
     map.addChild(layer);  
}
```

Но если с подгонкой скриптов по [инструкции](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/dg/concepts/map.html#layers) под свой сценарий есть сложности, быть может лучше получать готовый код из **[Конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/)** или через кнопку **[Поделиться](https://yandex.ru/support/maps/concept/get-map-reference.html#concept3)** на карте?

Comment: Я так уже пробовал.В этом и проблема,что он всеравно с таким кодом не выводит карту:(.Конструктор не подходит,потому что мне свои данные из базы данных надо будет выводить,а из кода конструктора это невозможно.

Comment: Пример точно рабочий – проверял в jsbin.com с привязкой к нему ключа. Если карты нет, значит вы некорректно привязываете ключ к домену (без чего API 3.0 работать не может), либо api-ключ нерабочий, либо работает на локальной машине, где этот домен в hosts не прописали. Может быть ещё что-нибудь, но это вам только поддержка и выяснит - с ключами вопросы только к ним.

Comment: Я создал ключ и в Ограничение по HTTP Referer прописал my.localhost как мне говорили в поддержке,вы написали что "либо работает на локальной машине, где этот домен в hosts не прописали" домен получается на котором я тесчу,и где прописать этот домен ,где находится строка hosts имею ввиду

Comment: Либо же в рефере надо сразу прописать рабочий домен?

Comment: Имеется в виду файл hosts, если вы тестируете на локальной машине: https://remontka.pro/izmenit-hosts/ Тот домен (my.localhost, например) нужно прописывать в этот файл и открывать тестовую страницу в браузере именно на my.localhost

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему этого нет в разделе "Руководство по переходу", и это действительно сбивает с толку, сам на этом потерял кучу времени, когда переходил с 2 на 3, но в разделе "Быстрый старт" это есть, ymaps3.YMap(...) создает только контейнер, далее в руководстве сказано, что для отображения карты нужно создать слои, у "YaCor" в ответе добавление слоя есть, но он не заострил на этом внимание:

```
 const layer = new ymaps3.YMapDefaultSchemeLayer();
 map.addChild(layer);
```